# Pandas use time_between with apply lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create 3 new boolean columns, in a datetime indexed dataframe, the value of which is 1 if the time of the day of each row falls

- in the time range 8:30 - 15:00 for column "US_market"
- in the time range 2:00 - 8:30 for column "EU_market"
- in the time range 00:00 - 2:00 and 15:00 - 00:00 for "AS_market"

I tried to use apply/lambda in this way

```
df_elaborated['US_market'] = df_elaborated.apply(lambda x:  1 if x.between_time('8:30', '15:00') else 0)
```

but I got this error message "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." Anyway the query

```
df_elaborated.between_time('8:30', '15:00')
```

works properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because apply would pass the entire column and you are trying to apply the `between_time()` logic to the full column instead of a value-by-value basis.

```
df_elaborated['US_market'] = np.where(df_elaborated.index.isin(df_elaborated.between_time('1:00','14:00').index),1,0)
```

Comment: thank you, testing your suggestions this df_elaborated['US_market'] = np.where(df_elaborated.between_time('8:30','15:00'),1,0) gives this error "Length of values (106873) does not match length of index (380414)", maybe it doesn't create the 0s?

Comment: You are not passing the column name, which is the column you want to evaluate the `between_time()` function for? I wrote 'time_column' as a placeholder because you didn't share enough information. See how I use `np.where(df_elaborated['time_column'].between_time()....` whereas you used `np.where(df_elaborated.between_time()` only.

Comment: Where is the `time` value you want to evaluate with `between_time()` is it a column? The index?

Comment: the datetime is in the index so that between_time shall be applied to the dataframe, not to dataframe.index. "np.where(df_elaborated.between_time('8:30','15:00'),1,0) " alone doesn't give any error, but the lenght of the result is different than the original df_elaborated dataframe.

Comment: Could you please try again now? I have edited my answer.

Comment: df_elaborated.index.map(lambda x:  1 if x.between_time('8:30', '15:00') else 0) -->  'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'between_time'

Comment: df_elaborated['US_market'] = np.where(df_elaborated.index.between_time('8:30','15:00'),1,0) --> 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'between_time'

Comment: Yes super, wondering if there are other more elegant solutions, but i have no ideas for now! ^_^ it seems strange there are no ways to understand if a row stays in a time range or not directly. Thank you for your suggestion, I keep this since it is working.

Comment: I have a similar feeling about elegance, but given you are working with 1D Arrays, it shouldn't be too bad performance-wise